# Error on DoCmd.OpenReport

Tags: ms-access, report, vba, runtime-error

I am getting a "Run-time error '3615' Type mismatch in expression" when I click the OK button on the Invoice Preview.

I open Main Menu >> select a Work Order ID >> click Invoice Preview >> accept default information >> click OK.  When I do I get the above error.  I cannot figure out why it is happening and have changed field types in both places and redone VBA code in various different formats thinking I coded wrong.

Can someone please help me get to the bottom of the error...

LINK REMOVED...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click that button, this is the *btnInvoicePreview_Click()* line which triggers error #3615, *"Type mismatch in expression."*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acPreview
```

The error occurs due to this clause in the *Invoice* report's Record Source query.

```sql
FROM
    Employee 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        (
            Client 
            INNER JOIN [Work Order]
            ON Client.ClientID = [Work Order].ClientID
        )
    ON Employee.EmployeeID = [Work Order].EmployeeID
```

`Employee.EmployeeID` is AutoNumber, which means its base datatype is Long Integer.  But `[Work Order].EmployeeID` is Text datatype.  So you get the *"type mismatch"* error because the query asks to join a numeric field with a text field.

Two ways to fix the problem ...

1. change the field type in one table so that both fields have the same datatype, or at least compatible datatypes
2. cast the datatype of one to match the datatype of the other ... 2 examples:  `ON Employee.EmployeeID = CLng([Work Order].EmployeeID)`; or `ON CStr(Employee.EmployeeID) = [Work Order].EmployeeID`

The first approach could require changes to other database objects (queries, forms, reports) so they don't break due to the field datatype change.  I don't know how extensive (and therefore painful) that would be.

The second approach could work, but the Access query designer will no longer be able to display the join condition in Design View.  A bigger problem would exist if the values you need to transform are not compatible with the function you need to cast them.  For example, all these throw errors: `CLng(Null)`; `CLng("")`; `CLng("foo")`

Comment: Thanks... now I can fix my report issues, but at least it shows up. LOL! :) Thanks